# Learning Embedded GSM

Tags: embedded, gsm

I'm interested in learning Embedded GSM from the ground up. Anybody here with tips and pointers on where I can get training/ books for this?

Comment: Could you please explain your rationale for going "embedded"? What part of GSM are you looking at? What is your use case?

Comment: Well, its about making devices that use embedded GSM to communicate with a central server to perform certain functions. For example, in telematics, you can have a chip in the car and via embedded GSM use it for vehicle tracking.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a GPS tracker for vehicles and trucks, I used SIMCOM GSM module which get internet connection via GPRS attach AT commands and later made a connection to a server where it reports its location.

You should google for "GSM MODEM AT COMMANDS" and look for examples of uses. I think the most common modules are SIMCOM and TELUS. From that examples you will learn about how to use a GSM module.

Talking about hardware, all modules works with a simple serial connection, tx/rx so you can wire them to a microcontroller uart or pc rs232.

Answer (score 1):

I was also learning AT commands so I could make my own programm that sends SMS.

Anyway: I found http://www.developershome.com/sms/ to be a very good help, when understanding how AT commands work.

It might not be quite what you want to use, but it will help you learn how to speak to a GSM modem

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend a good module for starting up. GM862-GPS module from Telit. You can either send AT commands to it via UART or you can write Python scripts and upload to it. In this way, you do not need a second MCU to send AT commands to it.

Buy one from https://www.sparkfun.com/products/280. There are some documentations about it in this link. There is even more documentations in Telit's website: http://www.telit.com/en/products.php?p_ac=show&p=7.

The best forum for this module is Roundsolutions. You can download a lot of tools for this Module from http://www.roundsolutions.com/techdocs/. Of them, the RSterm is the most important tool for sending AT commands via PC. This rsterm is specifically written for Telit GSM modules. It has a lot of shortcuts for AT commands. You can also use it to upload Python scripts to the GSM module.